# select all locators in maya and rename them all at once in Python

Tags: python, select, maya

How can select all the locators, joints and mesh in Maya and rename them all together? This is what I have so far:

```
for mesh in cmds.ls(type = ['mesh', 'joint', 'locator']):
                item = cmds.listRelatives(type= ['joint','locator','mesh'] p=1)[0]
                cmds.rename(item, item + "_" + text)
```

What am I doing wrong? I get an error:

```
# Error: TypeError: file <maya console> line 2: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' #
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to rename the transforms above the shapes, you need to actually pass in the shapes.  The way you've done it you're passing the selection to `listRelatives`, which returns `None` in older Maya's

```
locators = cmds.ls(type=('locator','mesh'), l=True) or []
loc_parents = cmds.listRelatives(*locators, p=True, f=True) or []
loc_parents.sort(reverse=True)
for lp in loc_parents:
    cmds.rename(lp, 'new_name')
```

When renaming you want to use long names -- in case you have multiple objects with the same short name under different parents -- and to work from the longest full paths to the shortest so you don't rename an object's parent and thereby change its path.

The 'or []'s make sure you get an empty list instead of None, so the script runs if there are no locators to work on too.

** edit **

updated to include meshes, per OP's request. For joints, there's no need to do  the listRelatives step -- but the long names and reordering are vital, since its easy for copied joints to create duplicate names